# Rings with group of units cyclic of prime order

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

For what prime numbers $p$ there exists a ring with identity and exactly $p$ invertible elements ?

**REMARK** It can be shown that for $p=5$ there is no such ring, so I am wondering for what values of $p$ such a ring exists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For $p=2$, $\mathbb F_3$ is an example.

Otherwise, $p$ is odd, so $-1$ is a unit of order $2$ unless it is equal to $1$, so $1=-1$, so $2=0$. We can form the ring:

$\mathbb Z[x]/(2,x^p-1)= \mathbb F_2[x]/(x^p-1)$. Any ring with exactly $p$ invertible elements admits a map from this universal ring whose image is the subring generated by the invertible elements, which must also have exactly $p$ invertible elements, so if there is any example, one example is quotient of this ring.

This ring is a product of finite fields of characteristic $2$, since $x^p-1$ has distinct roots over $\mathbb F_2$. So any quotient must be a product of finite fields of characteristic $2$. Since the unit group of a product is the product of the unit group, and the unit group, being cyclic, does not decompose as a product, it must be the unit group of  a single field of characteristic $2$.

So if $p\neq 2$, it must be of the form $2^n-1$ - a Mersenne prime.

Comment: That's a nice analysis.

Comment: Send $x$ to a generator of the group of units of $R$.

Comment: @Sally: Will isn't claiming that the kernel is $(x^p - 1)$. He only needs that the map is surjective, from which it follows that $R$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^p - 1)$, and then he classifies all such quotients.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $R$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^p - 1)$. How do you drive that $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^p - 1)$ has exactly $p$ invertible elements ?

Comment: @dimo: Will isn't claiming that either. The claim is that some direct factor of $\mathbb{F}_2[x](x^p - 1)$ has exactly $p$ invertible elements.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan you are right. That was a misunderstanding.

Comment: @WillSawin Nice answer, worth upvoting. Have any idea if we replace $p$ by $p^2$ or $p^n$ ??

Comment: The same argument says that the unit group of a ring with an odd number of units must be a product of cyclic groups whose orders are Mersenne numbers. So if one requires the group to be cyclic of prime power order, say $p^n$, then one requires $p^n$ to be a Mersenne number. If it need not be cyclic, there are more possibilities.